# OSMdroid : How to render offline map from a local sqlite archive

Tags: android, android-sqlite, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Programming with *Android Studio* and the `osmdroid` library.
I downloaded a portion of a map using the `cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync()` method. This method stores the map piece in a sqlite file in the `data/data/<package>/osmdroid/tiles` directory, chosen by me.
Now I want to use this map to load it offline in a mobile application.
I've tried to do it through all kinds of classes (`MapTileSqlCacheProvider, XYTileSource, OfflineTileProvider, ...`) but I can't get the map to appear.

How should I do it?

Comment: if you set the directory appropriately via the `Configuration.getInstance().set...` methods, and set the same map tile source as used in the download setup, it should load automatically.

Comment: can you post a snippet of you setting up the map? also, if you open the sqlite database, there is a column that will tell you the name of the tile source

Answer (score 0):

To download a portion of the map I do this:

```
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.OpenTopo);    
outputPath = "/data/data/<package>/files" + File.separator + "osmdroid" + File.separator  + "tiles" + File.separator;
outputName = outputPath + boxE6.name + ".db";

try {
    writer=new SqliteArchiveTileWriter(outputName);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(map,writer);
cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync(this, boxE6, 7, 13, new CacheManager.CacheManagerCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Download complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (writer!=null)
            writer.onDetach();
    } ...
```

To retrieve the stored map (in this case it is in the usa.db file) I try to do this:

```
map.setUseDataConnection(false);
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.OpenTopo);

File cache = new File(outputName);
Configuration.getInstance().setOsmdroidTileCache(cache);

mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((n+s)/2,(e+w)/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show how I store and load multiple sqlite Tiles, not just one.

The above answer from José Espejo Roig worked only partly for me. It worked almost fine for caching the tiles, but not for reading them. Writing down cache files though is also not complete. I have created my own code using as example: [Make a tile archive](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/cache/SampleCacheDownloaderArchive.java) from OSMDroid Github.

So to store potentially more than 1 tiles in a specific directory I use a code like below. It creates sequentially my_mapX.sqlite, where X are just stepped consecutive integers. So I get my_map1.sqlite, my_map2.sqlite and so on.

```
            private final String MAP_FILE_NAME = "my_map";
            private final String MAP_FILE_EXTENSION = ".sqlite";
```

//           ...

```
            Context ctx = getActivity();
            mMapView = new MapView(ctx);
            ((ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.osm_fragment)).addView(mMapView);
            mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.OpenTopo);

            ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(ctx);
            File root_directory = contextWrapper.getDir(ctx.getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File directory_osm = new File(root_directory, "osmdroid");
            directory_osm.mkdir();
            File directory = new File(directory_osm, "tiles");
            directory.mkdir();
            File[] nrFiles = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    if (name.endsWith(MAP_FILE_EXTENSION))
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            String osmdroidTile = directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + MAP_FILE_NAME + (nrFiles.length + 1) + MAP_FILE_EXTENSION;

            BoundingBox boxE6 = mMapView.getBoundingBox();

            SqliteArchiveTileWriter writer = null;

            try {
                writer = new SqliteArchiveTileWriter(osmdroidTile);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(mMapView, writer);
            SqliteArchiveTileWriter finalWriter = writer;
            int currZoom = (int)mMapView.getZoomLevelDouble();
            cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync(ctx, boxE6, currZoom, currZoom + 1, new CacheManager.CacheManagerCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTaskComplete() {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Download complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (finalWriter != null)
                        finalWriter.onDetach();
                }

                @Override
                public void updateProgress(int progress, int currentZoomLevel, int zoomMin, int zoomMax) {

                }

                @Override
                public void downloadStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void setPossibleTilesInArea(int total) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTaskFailed(int errors) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download complete with " + errors + " errors", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (finalWriter != null)
                        finalWriter.onDetach();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

This way I can create as many tile files as I want. Important is that they have ".sqlite" extension. ".db" extension didn't work for me.

Now to read these tiles I used again example from OSMDroid Github: [Sample SQLITE example](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/cache/SampleSqliteOnly.java). In OSMDroid Github example TileSource is being determined with IArchiveFile. I skipped that, as I assume I know what TileSource I used (in my case it is OpenTopo, as you can see). Then to read multiple offline tiles from the same TileSource (basing on example from OSMDroid) my code looks like this:

```
    //first we'll look at the default location for tiles that we support
    Context ctx = getActivity();
    mMapView = new MapView(ctx);
    ((ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.osm_fragment)).addView(mMapView);
    mMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);

    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(ctx);
    File root_directory = contextWrapper.getDir(ctx.getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String osmDir = root_directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "osmdroid" + File.separator + "tiles";
    File f = new File(osmDir);

    if (f.exists()) {

        File[] list = f.listFiles();

        ArrayList<File> sqliteArray = new ArrayList<>();

        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i].isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = list[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                if (!name.contains(".")) {
                    continue; //skip files without an extension
                }
                name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                if (name.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                //narrow it down to only sqlite tiles
                if (ArchiveFileFactory.isFileExtensionRegistered(name) && name.equals("sqlite")) {
                    sqliteArray.add(list[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        OfflineTileProvider tileProvider;
        if (sqliteArray.size() > 0) {
            try {
                tileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getActivity()), sqliteArray.toArray(new File[0]));
                mMapView.setTileProvider(tileProvider);
                mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.OpenTopo);
                mMapView.invalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), f.getAbsolutePath() + " dir not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```